# Changing Freeze Plugs on a Mazda 626

Tags: engine, cooling-system, diy, mazda-626

On a 98 Mazda 626 4 cylinder 2L engine where are the freeze plugs and how hard is it to replace them?

Comment: Core plugs are fairly simple to change but I can't comment on their location on your particular car.  This question relates; http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-to-remove-core-plugs-aka-freeze-plugs