# How to remove a stuck freeze plug

Tags: ford, f-150, freeze-plug

Got a 93 f150 with a 302 5.0 I’m replacing the freeze plug it’s on the back of block on the passenger side I’m using flathead an hammer but it won’t budge it’s in a tight spot is there anything else I can do to make it pop out [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It appears you've been trying [this method](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/25373/4152) and it hasn't been working for you. While your question is "technically" a duplicate of it, I believe it still valid considering the original answer isn't working for you.

Comment: Use a large screwdriver, put it on the edge of the cup and hit with hammer until it starts to twist out of the hole then use pliers to pull it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a pry-bar to get that out, sometimes using a spacer can help change the working angle fortuitously.

I have used a small puller to get them out - a block with a bolt and a "hook" into the plug can also work.

Comment: Couldn’t get it with pry bar

Comment: @user58082 had one once where we had to take the engine out...

Comment: Buddy just told me to put socket on it an hit it but it might fall in block

Comment: @user58082 that's another way, usually the space behind is not sufficient for the plug to go far as the cylinder wall is there and the water jacket is kept to a minimum. If you get it to move like that then it can come out easier...